# Enumerating SSH Algorithms from a remote node with python

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Looking for the equivalent in python of this command:

```
nmap -p22 -n -sV --script ssh2-enum-algos 192.168.10.221
```

The goal is to gather this information from remote node to build the proper `ssh.connect`.

For example, on newer server I can conenct using:

```
ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=password, pkey=pkey, look_for_keys=False)
```

while on older server I need to use the following code:

```
ssh.connect(oldserver, username=username, password=password, pkey=pkey, look_for_keys=False, disabled_algorithms=dict(pubkeys=["rsa-sha2-512", "rsa-sha2-256"]))
```

I'd like to write one comprehensive script and parametrize it instead of splitting into two batches the run.

Thanks!

Comment: did you check this project https://github.com/kaio6fellipe/ssh-enum ?

Comment: Thanks @VP. looks very promising. After a quick try it's not working as expected, there are some errors, I will dig deeper later. Thanks again!

Comment: if you are trying to learn the code, nothing better than debug and fix it. Happy hacking!